# Need help to determine if a poisson.test in R is the best approach and how to do it?

Tags: r, poisson-distribution

Hi supposed I have 1000 bins.  On average each bin has 100 blue balls and 20 yellow balls. What I like to do is to test whether each bin has significantly more blue or yellow ball than the average.

For example, if bin x has 200 blue balls and 25 yellow balls I would like to know if this bin has  blue or yellow ball then it is by chance?

is this is a good case use of a poisson test.  I tried looking at how R does but a bit confused how to set it up since there were no good examples.

to test for the blue ball in bin X is it as simple as
 `poisson.test(200,  r = 100)` ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to test *each* of the 1000 bins ?  ...  Would it make sense to compare the proportion of blue balls in each bin to the average proportion ?  That is, in your average, the proportion of blue balls is 0.833.  For your example, the proportion of blue balls is 0.889.  Is it essentially these proportions you want to compare:  `binom.test(200, (200+25), p=0.8333)` .  ?  Or are you more interested in the *counts*, like 200 blue balls is greater than 100 blue balls regardless of the number of yellow balls in the bin ?

Comment: @SalMangiafico that is a great question and yes, I would like to know about whether the 200 blue is greater than by chance irrespective of the yellow.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect 100 blue balls and 20 yellow balls and assume Poisson distributions for both of them, you could compute the probability of observing 200 blue balls or more using the cummulative probability function for the Poisson distribution:

Let $X$ be a r.v. for the number of blue balls in a bin, $X \sim Pois(\lambda_X=100)$, then

$$
P(X \ge 200) = 1 - F_X(200),
$$

where $F_X(x) = \sum_{i=0}^x \frac {e^{-\lambda} \lambda^i}{i!}$ is the cummulative distribution function with parameter $\lambda_X$ for the mean number of blue balls. One can choose a significance level $\alpha$ and inspect if the probability computed is less than the significance level.

The R code:

```r
alpha <- 0.05
p_value <- 1 - ppois(q = 200, lambda = 100)
if (p_value <= alpha) print("Significant difference!")
```

## Note:

This works only if you expect greater than the mean differences. If is not the case, you can perform the same procedure with $\alpha/2$ to account for both sides of the distribution.

Comment: The intended interpretation of this answer is unclear: does "observing 200 blue balls or more" mean *in one particular specified bin* (which appears to be what you compute) or does it mean *in any bin* (which would seem to be the relevant event to work with)?

Comment: I think you are correct, in the sense that the calculations answer the question about one specified bin, which is what I undestood with *"test for the blue balls in bin X"*. Can you point me in the direction for the *any bin* case?

Comment: It is possible the bin counts are independent.  (The OP doesn't give any relevant information about this.)  You could then frame the question in terms of testing, say, the maximum count, whose distribution is easily computed.  If the counts are not independent, it depends on *how* they fail to be independent. If this is a multinomial distribution, for instance, then with 1000 bins the dependency is so weak you can still proceed as if they were independent.

Comment: @dzegpi sorry I'm still a bit unclear. What would be the difference between your method vs something like, ` poisson.test(200,  r = 100)`  isn't this testing whether or not 200 is greater than chance given that the expected ratio is 100?

Comment: No. The `r` argument in `poisson.test` is the ratio between two rate parameters ($\lambda$) of two poisson random variables. See [poisson.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/poisson.test).